# Some dj track lists are missing from the soundcloud api

Tags: soundcloud

this is a problem that we have had for a couple of days now, when accesing the api (with the proper client id) in order to get the track list for 2 artists Dj Tiesto and AVICII we get no results, even if they have tracks on the current website, it cannot be over limit use because both djs have "Pro Unlimited" accounts so they don't have that problem.

As you can see  this link works perfectly
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/aviciiofficial?client_id=CLIENT_ID

But this other one http://api.soundcloud.com/users/aviciiofficial/tracks?client_id=CLIENT_ID, gives us an empty array, it happens no mather the ip or the user that is accesing the url, and many others authors that are also very popular don't have that problem.

Comment: Same problem, it seems it comes from soundcloud and they are not really reactive on it. And because they use another version of the api (v2) they may not even be aware.. the best option is to tell them

Comment: In their api website, they say that are listening into stackoverflow but not reply in here

Comment: I sent a mail, never know..

Comment: I am getting the same error. After doing some digging, it seems to work fine for users with id<1999999, but everything higher just returns an empty array.

Comment: but avicciofficial is id 1861068, and it happens too